# Can I import sql to my mini backend in next.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, vercel, es6-modules

I'm making a web app in next.js with typescript and to secure api keys I'm having a mini backend for some simple logic and api requests.

I have it deployed to vercel with a database in postgres and now I want to access that database in my index.ts file (the backend).

I access it through the fontend like this:
`import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres"`
but when I do the same in my backend I get this:
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I've tried adding `"type": "module"` in my package.json but then i recive this instead:
`TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"`

I've tried to import postgres with require aswell but I'm not sure about the syntax if it's even possible.

Can someone help me with this?